# Selecting fields by ordinal_Number, adapting MS-SQL-Code to MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

I need to extract fieldnames from a great number of tables, all having the same structure but unfortunately not the same field names. They are varying. So I need to check for the ordinal position of the fields required, because all tables have the same order of fields. I am Newbie on MySQL.

My MS-SQL-Guru gave me the 'Blueprint' of a procedure which does exactly what I want to do via sys.columns, but I cannot adapt it to MySQL. I want to have the resulting SELECT Statement for handover to the next batch of commands.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root2`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_GetColsFromSchema`(in lsid int)
BEGIN
SET @cols='';
SET @tbls = concat('MyTablePrefix_', lsid);

SELECT 
    @cols = @cols + column_name + ', '
FROM
    information_schema.columns
WHERE
    table_name = @tbls collate utf8_unicode_ci
        AND table_schema = 'MySchema'
        AND ordinal_position IN (2 , 4, 5, 7);

SET @cols = LEFT(@cols, length(@cols)-1);

SET @str = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' FROM ' + @tbls +';';
PREPARE stmt FROM @str;
EXECUTE stmt;
END
```

When calling this procedure I get `Error 1064` with the hint to `"... check the syntax near '0' at line 1"` which is confusing me.

Can you please get me on the right track?